# how to solve the problem of unable to run Sync project with Gradle Files?

Tags: android

After syncing project I have this error :

```
Cannot parse project property android.enableR8='' of type 'class java.lang.String' as boolean. Expected 'true' or 'false' in android studio.
```

[image]

the `gradleTampate.gradle` content in this picture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error states that you should edit the `gradleTampate.gradle` file and set the value of `android.enableR8` as a `boolean` type instead of a `string`.